# Printable IPv6 address and port from struct inet_sock

Tags: linux, network-programming, linux-kernel, kernel, ipv6

Do you know any way to print in readable format an ipv6 address and its port from the inet_sock struct?
My question has two parts. One is which are the structure members that have this information and the second is how to print them in readable format.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to do this from inside the kernel or from userspace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printk` has new modifiers which help printing inet addresses (I think since kernel 2.6.24). So you can try several ways, as an example:

```
//destination address
printk("%pI6 %d\n", my_inet_socket->pinet6->daddr, 
                    ntohs(my_inet_socket->inet_dport));
//source address
printk("%pI6 %d\n", my_inet_socket->pinet6->saddr, 
                    ntohs(my_inet_socket->inet_sport));
```

Here's how many modifiers you have and how they print the IPv6 address. You can check http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt for more info.

```
%pI6 0001:0002:0003:0004:0005:0006:0007:0008
%pi6 00010002000300040005000600070008
%pI6c 1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8
```

For older kernels you need to use NIP6 like this:

```
//destination address
printk(NIP6_FMT " %d\n", NIP6(my_inet_socket->pinet6->daddr), 
                         ntohs(my_inet_socket->inet_dport));
//source address
printk(NIP6_FMT " %d\n", NIP6(my_inet_socket->pinet6->saddr), 
                         ntohs(my_inet_socket->inet_sport));
```

As a last note, you can check net/ipv6/tcp_ipv6.c from the kernel itself. It has tons of examples. Hope this helps you

Comment: So the socket remains the same like in ipv4, right?
Thanks for your reply. i knew the new printk formats but I want to target and older kernels.

Comment: AFAIK ``inet_sock`` has ipv4 stuff all over it and ipv6 stuff located in pinet6. So I guess it remains the same.